# API Help Suggestion: /search - can we make tagged,nottagged description consistent with other list params

Tags: feature-request, documentation

on most other params that accept a semi-colon delimited list we see

```
list of tags questions must have, semicolon delimited
A single primary key identifier or a vectorized, semicolon-delimited list of identifiers.
```

on /search we see

```
List of tags delimited by semi-colons that must not be on a question
List of tags delimited by semi-colons of which at least one must be on a question
```

It would help machine readers if the search params were described with the terms `semicolon` and `delimited` adjacent anywhere in the description.

```
List of tags that must not be on a question, semicolon delimited
List of tags of which at least one must be on a question, semicolon delimited
```

**UPDATE**

found another one on `/questions` and `/questions/unanswered`

```
    tagged (optional)
    List of tags questions must have
    string
```